# ReactNative: Component inline and for navigation

Tags: react-native

I am beginning with ReactNative and try to get a component I can navigate to as well as use inline.

MyComp is the component. In Home I try to navigate to MyComp by a button as well as have it inline with .

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Alert, Image} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import Home from "./Home";
import MyComp from "./MyComp";

const navi = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: Home},
    MyComp: {screen: MyComp}
});

const App = createAppContainer (navi);
export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {navigate} from 'react-navigation';
import {MyComp} from "./MyComp";

export default class Home extends React.Component
{
    static navigationOptions = {title: 'At Home'};

    render()
    {
        return (
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1}}>
            <Button
                title={"Goto MyComp"} 
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MyComp')}/>

            <MyComp/>   {/* Compiler Error */}

            </View>
        );
  }
}
```

**MyComp.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';

export default class MyComp extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <View>
            <Text>Here I am</Text>
            </View>
    );
  }
}
```

But the inline produces an error.

> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Home`.

I am not sure whats the problem here. Is it not possible to use a component in both ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove brackets when u import component in home screen

change
 import {MyComp} from "./MyComp";

to
 import MyComp from "./MyComp";

Comment: Thanks! Whats the reason for that?

Comment: You are exporting the class as default. That's the syntax for importing default exports. Like the error message says, "you have mixed up default and named imports."